# How to read a portfile of a specific package in macports?

Tags: package-management, macports

I'm trying to find out what a specific port installs and I don't see a way on the ports page to read the portfile.

Background: There is a package called [openldap-devel](https://ports.macports.org/port/openldap-devel/), that I need, but I don't understand how it differs from `brew install openldap`. I hope to find a clue in the macports portfile on what exactly it's installing.

Comment: `brew install macports`? Huh? MacPorts is a competitor to Homebrew. I feel like there's an extra layer of confusion behind your question.

Comment: cleared it up. It was a typo

Answer (score 1):

MacPorts keeps its portfiles in `/opt/local/var/macports/sources/`.

You can also browse the portfiles on GitHub: https://github.com/macports/macports-ports

At a glance, MacPorts' openldap-devel port uses libressl as its SSL library, whereas Homebrew's openldap formula uses OpenSSL. There are also more dependencies listed for openldap-devel.

The *-devel* suffix in the names of open source package manager packages, traditionally indicates that it includes stuff like SDKs or other development tools that you need to be a developer/contributor to that open source project, but I'm not sure if that applies here.

Comment: Any idea from the portfile what it’s installing if it’s not just openldap? Like, how does the dev package differ. I need to install this, but switching from brew to Mac ports for this is not an option